# Unable to create a new guid from a request and compare it with a guid in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, guid

I'm getting a guid sent as my ID and want to compare it to a guid in my database so that I can pick out the correct record from the database.

Right now as the code is below the compiler complains that it can't recognize the guid format "Unrecognized Guid format."

[image]

```
TextBox68.Text = Request["ID"];

private Dagbok Get()
        {
            var idNr = new Guid(TextBox68.Text);


            Dagbok visadagbok = (from x in DagbokFactoryBase.All
                                 where (x.ID == idNr)
                                 select x).FirstOrDefault();

            return visadagbok;

        }
```

If I instead change the code to look like this, get the Request["ID"] directly when I create the "new guid" I get the error that I don't handle the null that might happen.

```
 TextBox68.Text = Request["ID"];

    private Dagbok Get()
            {
                var idNr = new Guid(Request["ID"]);


                Dagbok visadagbok = (from x in DagbokFactoryBase.All
                                     where (x.ID == idNr)
                                     select x).FirstOrDefault();

                return visadagbok;

            }
```

Not sure how to fix this problem.

Comment: This means the string in `Request["ID"]` is not parsable by `Guid`.

Comment: guid must be 16 characters and you should compare it with uniqueidentifier from the DB

Comment: What's the value in Request["ID"]?

Comment: The value in Request ["ID"] depends on what page you come from but this is one example of an ID "27be5724-acbd-11e2-816c-00a0c6000000" and that is the ID that is the unique identifier in my database for this table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to ensure that you get a proper value from the text field and exit with an error message in case you don't:

```
Guid guid;
var canBeParsedAsGuid = Guid.TryParse(TextBox68.Text, out guid);
```